# How to change the color of item selection radcombobox with a css style?

Tags: css, asp-classic, combobox, telerik, radcombobox

I was wondering if was possible to change the value of "background-color" for the selection of a radCombobox.

Here is the css code I used:
(I can change everything but not  the color of highlighted items ....)

```
div.RadComboBox_Metro .rcbInputCell INPUT.rcbInput
{
    background-color: #9BCDFF;
}
```

"Metro" being the name of the "skin" of my radcombobox

Thanks to all

**EDIT**- **12-12-2012**
Finally after a complete headache and several tries. My code below works for the first item highlighted, but not for others .... Have you any idea why?
Thanking you in advance

```
function cmbx_dbListUserOnClientSelectedIndexChanged(sender, args) {
                    var combo = $find("<%= cmbx_dbListUser.ClientID %>");
                    var highlightItem =  combo.get_highlightedItem();
                    if(highlightItem != null)
                    {
                        highlightItem.get_element().style.backgroundColor = "#9BCDFF";
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after a complete headache and several tries. My code below works

```
div.RadComboBoxDropDown_Metro .rcbHovered 
{
    border: 1px #7FB8FF !important;
    background-color: #7FB8FF !important;
}
.RadComboBox_Metro .rcbFocused .rcbArrowCell, .RadComboBox_Metro .rcbFocused .rcbReadOnly .rcbInputCell, .RadComboBox_Metro .rcbFocused .rcbReadOnly .rcbArrowCellHidden {
    background-color: #7FB8FF !important;
    border: 1px #5B85B7 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, and what I gathered, the only option for this is going to be a little javascript/jquery code:

```
$(".someSelect").change(function(ev){
     var targ = ev.target.selectedOptions[0];
    if($(targ).val() == $(targ).text()){
        $(".selected").removeClass('selected');
    }else{

    $(targ).parent().addClass('selected');
    $(targ).siblings('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $(targ).addClass('selected');
}
});​
```

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TNCodeMonkey/wC6nw/1/)

Comment: hello,
I wanted to know what part of the "combobox" represents ".selected" and "selected".
thank you very much.

Comment: Sorry i have not see the link on "fiddle". But your code work very fine on "combobox" but not on "radCombobox" from telerik..